# Best Way to "tag" data for fast parsing through matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, data-processing, xlsread

I collect data into an excel sheet through a labview program, the data is collected continuously at a regular interval and events are marked in the file in one of the columns with TaskA_0 representing the start of an event, and TaskA_1 representing the end.  this is a snippet of the data:

```html
Time            Data 1      Data 2      Data 3      Data 4      Event Name
13:38:41.888    0.719460527 0.701654664 0.221332969 0.012234448 Task A_0
13:38:41.947    0.437707516 0.588673334 0.524042112 0.309975646 Task A_1
13:38:42.021    0.186847503 0.589175696 0.393891242 0.917737946 Task B_0
13:38:42.115    0.44490411  0.073132298 0.897701096 0.633815257 Task B_1
13:38:42.214    0.833793601 0.004524633 0.40950937  0.808966844 Task C_0
13:38:42.314    0.953997375 0.055717025 0.914080619 0.166492915 Task C_1
13:38:42.414    0.245698313 0.066643778 0.515709814 0.606289696 Task D_0
13:38:42.514    0.248038367 0.862138045 0.025489223 0.352926629 Task D_1
```

Currently I load this into matlab using `xlsread` , and then run a `strfind` to locate the row indices of the event markers in order to break my data up into tasks where each each task is the data in the adjacent columns between TaskA_0 and TaskA_1 (here there is no data between but normally there is, also between event names there are blank cells normally). Is this the best method for doing this? Once I have it in separate variables I then perform identical actions on each variable, usually basic statistics and some data plotting. If I want to batch process my data I have to rewrite these lines over and over to get the data broken up by task. Which even I know is wrong and horribly inefficient but I don't know how better to do this.

```
[Data,Text]= xlsread('C:\TestData.xlsx',2); %time column and event name column end up in text, as does the data headers, hence the +1 for the row indices
IndexTaskAStart = find(~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(Text(:,2),'TaskA_0')))+1;
IndexTaskAEnd = find(~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(Text(:,2),'TaskA_1')))+1;
TaskAData = Data([IndexTaskAStart:IndexTaskAEnd,:];
```

Now I can perform analysis on columns in TaskAData, and repeat the process for the remaining tasks.

Comment: Are the event names for the start always `Task x_0` and the end `Task x_1`? Are your tasks only A-D or are other letters present?

Comment: @excaza I am trying to set it so that the task names are consistent so yes they should always be Task X_0, Task@_1, There can be more than 4 tasks yes, but not more than 26 so it seemed like a good naming convention, feel free to suggest a better one :)

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you cannot change the format of the files, but do know which tasks you're searching for, you can still automate the search by creating a list of task names, just appending _0 and _1 onto the task names to search. Then do not create individual named variables but store in a cell array for easier looping:

```
tasknames = {'Task A', 'Task B', 'Task C'}

for n = 1:numel(tasknames)
    first = find(~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(Text(:,2),[tasknames{n},'_0'])))+1;
    last = find(~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(Text(:,2),[tasknames{n},'_1'])))+1;
    task_data{n} = Data(first:last, :);
    % whatever other analysis you require goes here
end
```

If there are a large number of tasknames but they follow some pattern, you might prefer to create them on the fly instead of preallocating a list in `tasknames`.